# Problem with rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro foxy -y in tutorial in foxy

Tags: ros2, tf2-ros

Im fairly new to ROS and was trying to go through the ROS2 Tutorial. When Ive reached the ["Writing a static broadcaster tutorial"](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Intermediate/Tf2/Writing-A-Tf2-Static-Broadcaster-Py.html) and tried to check for missing dependencies with `rosdep install -i --from-path src --rosdistro foxy -y` , Ive received the following message:
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
learning_tf2_py: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [tf2_ros_py]
Does anyone know how this problem can be fixed?
(I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and foxy)

Ive already tried to delete the created package and to create a new one but this error keeps coming up nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial provided an incorrect key for tf2. You need to put tf2_ros as dependency in your package.xml instead of tf2_ros_py.

Ref: official list of keys for foxy: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/foxy/distribution.yaml